# Installing Ambari MPack Fails Python Usage Message

Tags: python-2.x, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Trying to install [Amabri Management Pack](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF2/HDF-2.1.1/bk_dataflow-ambari-installation/content/install-management-pack.html) and i cannot get the command to run

```
ambari-server install-mpack --mpack=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDF/centos6/2.x/updates/2.1.1.0/tars/hdf_ambari_mp/hdf-ambari-mpack-2.1.1.0-2.tar.gz --purge --verbose
```

> Using python  /usr/bin/python Usage:
>           {start|stop|restart|setup|setup-jce|upgrade|status|upgradestack|setup-ldap|sync-ldap|set-current|setup-security|setup-sso|refresh-stack-hash|backup|restore|update-host-names|check-database|db-cleanup|enable-stack}
>   [options]
>           Use   --help to get details on options available.
>           Or, simply invoke ambari-server.py --help to print the options.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on CentOS 6, my repo satellite had Ambari for CentOS 7. Running yum install ambari-server --nogpgcheck caused the wrong version to be forced onto CentOS 6.